# addViolation() is deprecated: how to replace it?

Tags: symfony-services

How to adapt the following code to avoid the deprecation of `addViolation()` according to https://www.drupal.org/node/3238432 ?

```
class MyValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    if (!$this->isValid($items)) {
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message); // How to adapt this line?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the deprecation message is a false alarm. In contrast to the methods mentioned in the change record addViolation() is not marked as internal in Symfony 6 and if Drupal removes this method they will replace it with Symfony code.

Comment: thank you. Is this means that the deprecation code has been falsely added to the addViolation() method... Some kind of Core bug I would say?

Comment: It's not falsely added, it's clear they want to remove this implementation of the method. This doesn't change the usage of the method, though, it is used the same way in Symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown in the question doesn't need to be changed: Once [Start using the class Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuilder instead of copied classes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3247384) is fixed, `$this->context` won't contain anymore an instance of [`\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\ExecutionContext`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Validation%21ExecutionContext.php/class/ExecutionContext/9.3.x) but [`\Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContext`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21validator%21Context%21ExecutionContext.php/class/ExecutionContext/9.3.x).
As the documentation says, classes that extend [`ConstraintValidator`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21validator%21ConstraintValidator.php/class/ConstraintValidator/9.3.x) should just assume that `$this->context` is an object implementing [`ExecutionContextInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21validator%21Context%21ExecutionContextInterface.php/interface/ExecutionContextInterface/9.3.x), not which class is actually used. With that assumption, the changes introduced by that issue won't influence contrain validator classes (except for the fact the deprecation message won't be anymore triggered).